# Question regarding TimeDistributed(conv1D) with kernel_size > 1

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I am trying to understand how conv1D works in keras. 
If I try,

```
timestep = 10
input_dim = 1
newmodel.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1,activation='relu',input_shape=(timestep, input_dim)))
newmodel.summary()
```

I understand that 1D conv works as shown in the image.

[image: Text]

I expect an output layer (None,8,64).

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_56 (Conv1D)           (None, 9, 64)             192       
=================================================================
Total params: 192
Trainable params: 192
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now if I use

```
   timestep = 10
   input_dim = 1

   newmodel.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2,activation='relu'), input_shape=(None, timestep, input_dim)))
   newmodel.summary()
```

I get the output shape,

```
Model: "sequential_24"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_35 (TimeDis (None, None, 9, 64)       192       
=================================================================
Total params: 192
Trainable params: 192
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here a conv1D layer is applied to each time step of the input, but each timestep of the input is a (1,1) vector.

Since the convolution window is along the time, how can I have kernel_size > 1 because the kernel_size has to be less than the length of the vector which in our case is 1.

How can I make sense of this?

Comment: I think right now it thinks the "time" channel is "none" based on the specification here: `input_shape = (None, timestep, input_dim)`. As TimeDistributed adds another "slice" to the layer that it wraps around it would be a "time x (time, feature size)" requirement, when you wrap TimeDistributed around a Conv1D

Comment: Ok thanks I understood, from keras documentation, "The input should be at least 3D, and the dimension of index one will be considered to be the temporal dimension."